# Aptana 3.0 Rails debugger error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, aptana

Seeing this error while trying to launch debugger in Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.1.201104291443

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.4) listens on 127.0.0.1:32650
Fatal exception in DebugThread loop: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. - socket(2)
Backtrace:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `initialize'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `new'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `start_control'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `initialize'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `new'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `start_control'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:96:in `start_server'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:100:in `debug_program'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
  from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/rdebug-ide:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug on Windows when using a shell that has spaces in the path. See https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/2548-using-our-installed-portablegit-doesnt-set-up-env-properly

The bug has been fixed in development and will be in the upcoming 3.0.2 release. There's a Tender support discussion where a user has found a workaround in the meantime, adding a RUBYLIB ENV var to the launch configuration: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2896-issues-with-aptana-30-radrails